# How to add TOOLTIP in Yii2 NavBar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have tried lot of suggestions made by peoples in the websites, forums everywhere. ([Activating Tooltip](http://webtips.krajee.com/activating-bootstrap-3-tooltip-popover-yii-site/)) but still i haven't success. i was added this coding in my own layout file. **views/layouts**

**NavBar widget coding**

```
 'items' => [  
            [
              'label' => '<span style="font-size:1.3em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>', 
              'url' => ['/site/controlPanel'],
              'options' =>[ 
                              'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',  
                              'data-placement' => 'tooltip',
                              'title' =>'Control Panel', 
                              'class' => 'tooltipStyle'
                          ],
            ],
            [
              'label' => '<span style="font-size:1.3em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>', 
              'url' => ['/site/controlPanel'],
              'options' =>[ 
                              'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',  
                              'data-placement' => 'tooltip',
                              'title' =>'Day Summary',
                              'class' => 'tooltipStyle'
                          ],
            ],
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltipStyle + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
background-color: #000;
}
.tooltipStyle + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { 
    border-bottom-color:#ff0; 
}
```

Eventually i just want to get the out put like this

[image]

After did some modifications to my coding, this output is showing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do adding the title to the label in span ... this way

```
'items' => [  
        [
          'label' => '<span style="font-size:1.3em;" 
                   class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"</span>'
            . '  Control Panel', 
          'options' =>[ 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',  
                        'data-placement' => 'tooltip',
                         'title' =>'Notifications', 
                          'class' => 'myTooltipClass']
          'url' => ['/site/controlPanel'],
          'data-toggle' => 'tooltip',
          'title' => 'Control Panel',
        ],
```

And in you css add this class (eg: for changing the color )

```
.myTooltipClass + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {background-color: #ff0;}
.myTooltipClass + .tooltip > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color:#ff0; }
```

Comment: I  have used this many times..and i know it's working .. then  try removing data-toggle and data-placement..

Comment: I'm looking for how to use the build in tool tip feature of bootstrap. bad luck not working still

Comment: Thanks !!. it's working now. but i need the style same as shown in the image. how can i do that ?

Comment: Well, this is another question for style i think you must work on css, and try take a look for some sample in bootstrap..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but your answer is not complete. I just need to get the exact style as shown in the picture. do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Yes i know.. add a class  and format the css properly.. i have upate the answer..

Comment: Nope, styles are not working. still showing the white background